# Android Application bugs on Samsung tablet, but works great on Nexus 5?

Tags: android

I'm confused and I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Currently an application I have built using my Nexus 5 as a test device works great.

I recently plugged it into a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, and some of the functions are not working correctly.

For example I am using the Google Maps API, on my Nexus it will focus on your current location. If you don't have location enabled, then it will default to a set city. This works great on the Nexus, however the tablet is focusing on the middle of the pacific ocean. It displays the little blue location dot where it should, but it doesn't focus on it when opened?

Another example is a YouTube webview. On Nexus, the YouTube videos play through the `WebView`. This changes on the tablet as none of the videos will play. It just displays a grey box instead.

Anyone got any ideas?

I'm going to start playing with the YouTube API and integrate that to fix the YouTube problem, but I have no idea what's happening with Google Maps.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if (myLocation == null) {
        latitude = -36.916278;
        longitude = 174.795372;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    } else {
        // Get latitude of the current location
        latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8));
}
```

Heres the map setup code that should work on the tablet. Works great on the Nexus 5.

Comment: You have to show code. Otherwise there're could be about million reasons of your problems.

Comment: Small differences are quite normal business and you have to dig into details why it works on one and not on the other device. Usually you'll find a way to resolve these issues.

Comment: Samsung always has issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newCameraPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition))

Should be something like this:

```
LatLng  latLng;
if (myLocation == null) {
    latitude = -36.916278;
    longitude = 174.795372;
    latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
} else {
    // Get latitude of the current location
    latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

}

CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(latLng, 8)
// Zoom in the Google Map
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
```

Comment: Works a treat thanks! The only thing i changed was the following;

googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));

Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome. I've changed animateCamera() to moveCamera() on my post to be consistent with your code